# c++ share parent attribute between two instances of child

Tags: c++, inheritance

Say I have a parent class `class Parent` and two types of children `class Son`
and `class Daughter`. The attributes that are common to `Son` and `Daughter`
are defined in `Parent`

Now I define one instance of `Son` and one of `Daughter`. They have different
methods and can do different things but when `Son` does something, `Daughter`
waits (and reciprocally). The actions of either `Son` or `Daughter` are
redefining some attributes in `Parent` that should be taken into account by
both children.

The first idea to achieve that was to set those attributes to `static` so if
`Daughter` changes something, it will also affect `Son`. But my problem is that
it will affect all instances of `Son` and `Daughter` and I want only to affect
those in the same "family".

Here is a pseudo code that exposes my problem :

```
class Parent{
    public:
    /*define some constructors and parent stuff*/

    void set_family_name(std::string f){ family_name = f; }

    protected:
        std::string family_name;
}

class Son : public Parent{
    public:
    /*define some constructors and son stuff*/
}

class Daughter : public Parent{
    public:
    /*define some constructors and daughter stuff*/
}

int main(){
    Son JohnSmith(/*some attributes*/);
    Daughter AnnaSmith(/*some attributes*/);

    Son BobWeston(/*some attributes*/);

    JohnSmith.set_family_name("Smith"); /*should also affect AnnaSmith but not BobWeston*/
}
```

Is there a way to connect two instances of child so that when one changes a
parent argument it is reflected on the other one but not in all of them ?

The first solution that comes to my mind, would be to set some other class,
`class FamilyAttribute` that would be referenced in `Parent`. Something like :

```
class FamilyAttribute{
    public:
    /*define some constructors and family stuff*/

    void set_family_name(std::string f){ family_name = f; }

    private:
        std::string family_name;
}

class Parent{
    public:
    /*define some constructors and parent stuff*/

    void set_family_name(std::string f){ attribute->set_family_name(f); }

    protected:
        FamilyAttribute* attribute;
}
```

But this will make me rewrite all methods and this will also multiply the
number of methods calls. It also seems strange because now `Parent` is only
useful for polymorphism (which I need).

Is there a neater way ?

Comment: This sounds like a horribly confused hierarchy that violates the Liskov Substitution Principle. Are you actually trying to model family relationships, such as Parent/Son, or are you just using a horrible metaphor to describe your real problem? With this model a Son IS-A Parent, which seems wrong.

Comment: @JonathanWakely bad example, my bad ! sorry (could replace Parent by Relatives :-))

Comment: This is a horrible example, because you are using "parent" and "child" in two different ways, one in the common OO "parent class" and "child class" terminology (which I hate, it causes misunderstanding and it's better to talk about base classes and derived classes) and in another way where you are talking about human family relationships.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Point taken, my next question will be better

Answer (score 2):

C++ supports several ways of sharing variables, but none of them lets you control sharing instance-by-instance. The language has no idea of the concept of "family", so you have to build it yourself.

Your solution that introduces a common `FamilyAttribute` in the `Parent` is correct. You may want to tweak the implementation, e.g. by renaming the class to `Family`, or replacing a pointer with a reference, but the direction is absolutely right: you need to define a separate class to represent shared data, and configure instances that share a family as needed.

Note that your implementation of `Son` and `Daughter` deriving from a `Parent` is very likely flawed, because public derivation suggest that `Son` or `Daughter` could be used as a `Parent` (see [*Liskov Substitution Principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). In order to capture what's common among `Son`s and `Daughter`s without regard to their gender, you should probably rename your `Parent` class to `Child`.

Comment: thanks ! i will look into that direction ! still have a question connected to your answer. why and how should I replace the pointer by a reference ?

Comment: something else, would it be good to define that seperate class as a nested class ?

Comment: @PinkFloyd Using a reference in place of a pointer suggests to the readers of your code that the shared thing is not optional (because references cannot be set to `NULL` legally). Nesting the shared class may be a good idea if it is an implementation detail closely connected to the class (i.e. `FamilyAttribute`). If you decide to make it a first-class citizen available to all, i.e. a `Family`, then it should remain a top-level class.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to connect two instances of child so that when one changes a parent argument it is reflected on the other one but not in all of them ?

Not automatically in the type system, no.

There is no way to have some instances of a type connected to other arbitrary instances of a type without using something like a pointer to connect them.

It seems like what you want to model is Person, with two types of concrete sub-class, Son and Daughter (or Man and Woman), so that Son IS-A Person, and Daughter IS-A Person.

The family name is an attribute, which should be modeled by a HAS-A relationship, so that a Person HAS-A pointer to a FamilyName object, and several Person objects can refer to the same FamilyName. (A `shared_ptr` would be the best way to model that so that ownership is managed correctly).

> But this will make me rewrite all methods and this will also multiply the number of methods calls.

It's not possible to answer this because you haven't shown any methods so it's not possible to know why it causes you to rewrite them.

> It also seems strange because now Parent is only useful for polymorphism (which I need).

Either I don't understand what you mean or I don't understand why that's strange or why it's a problem. If you need polymorphism, why is it strange to have a base class that provides the polymorphic interface?

Comment: again, I agree with you that my example was a bad one... to answer your last point, I don't think it's strange to have a base class that provides the polymorphic interface, I meant that it's now its only role because all the "hard" work is redistributed to `FamilyAttribute`.

Comment: Well if you need the "work" to be something that is shared between separate instances then it has to be done outside the Parent.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce the following private member to the base class:

```
static std::map<FamilyId, FamilyAttributes> FamilyPropertyMap;
```

FamilyId would be a typedef to the unique identifier you want to sort your families by; maybe just a string for a name, maybe something else.
FamilyAttributes would be an object that stores the common data, that all derived objects with the same "family" want to have shared access to. A struct storing all the variables, you want common access to, might be sufficient at first.

You could then add the following public or protected method to the base class:

```
   FamilyAttributes& getMyFamiliesAttributes(){return FamilyPropertyMap[family_name];}
```

I'm assuming that you use the string family_name as key for the map here.
This way, you restrict access for all derived objects to the data of their specific "family". If someone outside of the family should be able to access family property make the method public, if only the derived objects should be able to handle the data internally, make it protected.

The static map might not be the most elegant or OO solution, but it has the advantage, that you don't have to deal with pointers. Make sure to either properly initialize the family_name string or check for an empty string when accessing the map.